# What is the format of the electron-density data in a CHGCAR file?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, electron-density, fortran

Rephrasing the above, what is the pattern in which the electron-density data is stored in the CHGCAR file?

I understand that the electron density data in a CHGCAR file is in the form of a 3D Fortran array, but I believe that such electron density data should be stored in 3 columns (NX,NY,NZ). Instead we see the presence of 5 columns.
***What I am requesting, is a comprehensive description of the 5-column electron density data present in every CHGCAR file, and the significance of every column present to represent the electron-density data.***

I have shown the part of the CHGCAR data that I am referring to, is shown below:

```
  64   64   64
 0.27296628474E+03 0.27129538645E+03 0.26632236747E+03 0.25816527382E+03 0.24701868651E+03
 0.23315320780E+03 0.21691723332E+03 0.19873896341E+03 0.17912393717E+03 0.15864307047E+03
 0.13790873569E+03 0.11754046377E+03 0.98125176377E+02 0.80177959210E+02 0.64108387081E+02
 0.50195641939E+02 0.38574367354E+02 0.29232778335E+02 0.22024079253E+02 0.16690923309E+02
 0.12900228129E+02 0.10283187627E+02 0.84752878195E+01 0.72047216409E+01 0.63226226628E+01
 0.57166613639E+01 0.53025284991E+01 0.50199593897E+01 0.48277275324E+01 0.46988015018E+01
 0.46162530737E+01 0.45701256193E+01 0.45552760083E+01 0.45701256193E+01 0.46162530737E+01
 0.46988015018E+01 0.48277275324E+01 0.50199593897E+01 0.53025284991E+01 0.57166613639E+01
 0.63226226628E+01 0.72047216409E+01 0.84752878195E+01 0.10283187627E+02 0.12900228129E+02
 0.16690923309E+02 0.22024079253E+02 0.29232778335E+02 0.38574367354E+02 0.50195641939E+02
 0.64108387081E+02 0.80177959210E+02 0.98125176377E+02 0.11754046377E+03 0.13790873569E+03
 0.15864307047E+03 0.17912393717E+03 0.19873896341E+03 0.21691723332E+03 0.23315320780E+03
 0.24701868651E+03 0.25816527382E+03 0.26632236747E+03 0.27129538645E+03 0.27129538645E+03
..................... over a hundred thousand lines of data
```

Comment: Related discussion thread: https://theory.cm.utexas.edu/henkelman/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2717

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Vaspwiki](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/CHGCAR), the CHGCAR file writes out the density using this Fortran snippet:

`WRITE(IU,FORM) (((C(NX,NY,NZ),NX=1,NGXF),NY=1,NGYF),NZ=1,NGZF)`

Basically, this will iterate through the coordinates in the order X, then Y, then Z. For your case, this would look something like with $(N_x,N_y,N_z)$: $(1,1,1),(2,1,1),...,(64,1,1),(1,2,1),(2,2,1),...$

The five columns don't have any particular meaning, the screen would just become too cluttered if you tried to include more values per line, so they just print five at a time. This is what the `FORM` option in the code above is doing; they don't include the code for the format on the Vaspwiki, but if the code were just `write(iu,*)`, it would try to print all these values on one line until it ran out of buffer space.

To find the actual coordinate values of a grid point from its index, you can convert using $$(N_x,N_y,N_z)=\frac{N_x-1}{N_{GXF}}\vec{a}+\frac{N_y-1}{N_{GYF}}\vec{b}+\frac{N_z-1}{N_{GZF}}\vec{c}$$ where $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are the lattice vectors.

Comment: Okay, then how does VESTA rearrange the data to visualize it?

Comment: @PranoyRay I don't know about VESTA and it potentially could warrant another question. But I suspect it just reads the values from the CHGCAR into a 3D array and performs whatever visualization with this data. Is there something missing from my description that you think would be needed to visualize the density?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your answer is perfect.

Comment: Since this discussion warrants another question, I have posted it here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6225/how-to-process-electron-density-data-in-chgcar-for-better-handling

Answer (score 2):

`VESTA` can understand the data format of `CHGCAR` outputted by `VASP`. You just need to move `CHGCAR` to `CHGCAR.vasp` and then open with `VESTA`.

Comment: Unecessary to rename with the .vasp suffix